# How to get epoch time with trace-cmd (frontend for ftrace)?

Tags: linux-kernel, timestamps, ftrace

```
  <...>-32578 [001] **133767.868869**: kfree:            call_site=ffffffff810e6f06 ptr=(nil)
```

How to make `trace-cmd` report time in epoch time? The time by default is I think time since application uptime. This is a requirement to pinpoint exact time of the event.

`trace-cmd list -O` options doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

The time `133767.868869` in this case is the time since the cpu booted (assuming that you have not altered the value of the file conventionally mounted at /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_clock). The question is how much accuracy you need for `the exact time of the event`. If say to the nearest second is ok, then you can just add the output of

```
  date | cat > /dev/null # Make sure programs are in cache
  set -- $(date +%s.%N) $(cat /proc/uptime)
  echo "$1-$2" | bc
```

which works out the time that the system booted. This assumes that your clock is set reasonably.

If you want something with greater accuracy then you should probably do something like

```
  echo global > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_clock # Once only
  date +"Time=%s.%N" > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker
```

several times, and compare the `Time=` messages with the timestamps to get an estimate of how much the values are offset and how much variability there is.

Once you know the amount to adjust by, then you can either do the one off calculation to see when a particular event happened or you can write a script in awk or perl or python or ... to adjust the column in the output.

Comment: Is it not possible to pick up the exact microsecond time offset that ftrace is picking up? I mean, it must get it from somewhere, and if it is system boot time, then it must be available somewhere for ftrace to pick up.

Comment: @themagicalyang The number is the time since the cpu booted. Think about waking up. Before you look at a clock or hear the time from a tv or radio you don't know what the time is, but you can still say "I've been awake for 5 minutes".   If something happens, say a clap of thunder, you can say "that happened 7 minutes after I woke up" but your friend might say that it was only 2 minutes after he woke. Neither of you can say the time it happened. Can you explain the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: I was trying to debug jitters in a real time application thread which is very latency sensitive. So, from the logs I can map what time a event/schedswitch/interrupt etc. occurred in ftrace report and at what time application did some work (as per application logs).

Comment: So what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: @icarus, finally got around to using this (not having root on my own machines sucks), it works fantastically, I'm not sure what themagicalyang was complaining about.

Comment: @Sam Good to know. As you can see we haven't heard back in 2 years.